# auth0 - default group for user after registration

Tags: auth0

Any idea if it's possible to assign default group to user as result of registration?
So far we found only a way to do it only as part of user login process but see no similar way for registration process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auth0 doesn't yet support running custom code at registration time.

A workaround, however, could be to detect the first login (usually after sign up) and act upon it:

```
function (user, context, callback) {

  // if it is the first login (hence the `signup`)
  if (context.stats.loginsCount === 1 ) {

    // initialize app_metadata
    user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};

    // set a default group
    user.app_metadata.groups = ['default'];

    // store the app_metadata
    auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata)
      .catch(function(err){
        callback(err);
      });
  } 

  // continue
  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, going to employ this approach for the moment!